# Can I prevent an inherited virtual method from being overridden in subclasses?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have some classes layed out like this

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Render()
    {
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public override void Render()
    {
        // Prepare the object for rendering
        SpecialRender();
        // Do some cleanup
    }

    protected virtual void SpecialRender()
    {
    }
}
class C : B
{
    protected override void SpecialRender()
    {
        // Do some cool stuff
    }
}
```

Is it possible to prevent the C class from overriding the Render method, without breaking the following code?

```
A obj = new C();
obj.Render();       // calls B.Render -> c.SpecialRender
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can seal individual methods to prevent them from being overridable:

```
public sealed override void Render()
{
    // Prepare the object for rendering        
    SpecialRender();
    // Do some cleanup    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the sealed keyword in the B class's implementation of Render:

```
class B : A
{
    public sealed override void Render()
    {
        // Prepare the object for rendering
        SpecialRender();
        // Do some cleanup
    }

    protected virtual void SpecialRender()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In B, do

```
protected override sealed void Render() { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

try `sealed`

```
class B : A
{
  protected sealed override void SpecialRender()
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}

class C : B
  protected override void SpecialRender()
  {
    // not valid
  }
}
```

Of course, I think C can get around it by being `new`.

Answer (score 0):

An other (better ?) way is probablby using the new keyword to prevent a particular virtual method from being overiden:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Render()
    {
    }
}
class B : A
{
    public override void Render()
    {
        // Prepare the object for rendering       
        SpecialRender();
        // Do some cleanup    
    }
    protected virtual void SpecialRender()
    {
    }
}
class B2 : B
{
    public new void Render()
    {
    }
}
class C : B2
{
    protected override void SpecialRender()
    {
    }
    //public override void Render() // compiler error 
    //{
    //}
}
```

Comment: Any explanation why is this better? Sealed has a rather clean meaning. It says "After some thinking I came to the conclusion that this should never be overridden".

Answer (score -1):

yes. If you mark a method as Sealed then it can not be overriden in a derived class.